# Getting filename from IoDevice in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a function which tries to read from an open IoDevice.
In the case of {error, Reason} I want to print out the filename.

How can I do that?

Source code:

```
read_file(IoDevice) ->
    case read_file(IoDevice, []) of
        {ok, OpCodes} ->
            OpCodes;
        {error, Reason} ->
            io:format("Unable to read file ~s: ~s ~n", [File, Reason]),
            []
    end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `IoDevice` can be either a process ID or a file descriptor. If it's a process ID, you can use `file:pid2name/1` to obtain the filename:

```
1> {ok,IoDevice} = file:open("/tmp/x.erl", [read]).
{ok,<0.43.0>}
2> {ok, Filename} = file:pid2name(IoDevice).
{ok,"/tmp/x.erl"}
```

If the `IoDevice` is a file descriptor, though, `pid2name` won't work, and I don't know of a way to obtain the filename in that case.